# How to import a module from a subfolder in python3 (with empty __init__.py)

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I want to call a function from a file in a sub folder. I would prefer do do it statically. I use empty `__init__.py` files as I've read that in simple cases they can be empty(and mine couldn't be an simpler) or that from 3.5 on I don't need them at all. But I am open to filling them.

I have the following file structure:

```
test
├── callfoo.py   (main)
├── __init__.py  (empty)
└── folder
    ├── submodule.py
    └── __init__.py (empty)
```

callfoo.py:

```
#import statement wanted

def main():
    foo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

submodule.py

```
def foo():
    print('foo')
```

For the import statement I've tried:

`import test.folder.submodule`
`from test.folder import submodule`
`from test.folder.submodule import foo`

each resulting in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.folder'`
I'm a bit confused here because they are taken straight from the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

`import .folder.submodule` -> `invalid syntax`
`importlib.import_module('test.folder.submodule')`
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.folder'

This works:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("submodule", "/home/.../test/folder/submodule.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
```

But I don't really want to do it dynamically especially not for several files.

This [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x) deals with my error message but not with subfolders as far as I can tell (it works fine for me with `submodule.py` on the same level as `callfoo.py`)

There are several questions dealing with imports from sub folders but I couldn't make them work for me.
I hope to have provided a dead simple problem formulation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's suppose we have this folders/files architecture:

```
test
├── callfoo.py
└── folder
    ├── __init__.py
    └── submodule.py

1 directory, 3 files
```

**callfoo.py**:

```
from folder.submodule import foo

def main():
    foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**submodule.py**:

```
def foo():
    print('foo in submodule')
```

now place your self at the same level's folder of `callfoo.py` and run:

```
$ python3 callfoo.py
```

Output:

```
> foo in submodule
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Can you tell me why the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) (6.4) uses the top level package, in my case test?

Comment: @peer in order to run the example in the documentation you need to set `sys.path` correctly. it says: `When importing the package, Python searches through the directories on sys.path looking for the package subdirectory.`

Comment: This works if you run python from the same directory as callfoo.py, but what if callfoo.py is part of a installed package, being imported from an arbitrary directory?

Comment: this works at home for me but when i try it on the school computer it just says the module isn't found

Comment: @Hippolippo check this [documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Comment: @ChihebNexus I found out what the problem is, it was the way I was importing it that messed it up.