# pyperclip installed but not working in my batch file

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, pyperclip

I have installed pyperclip, and it works when I use IDLE

```
>>> import pyperclip
>>> pyperclip.copy('hello')
>>> pyperclip.paste()
'hello'
>>>
```

but when I use my batch file it says that there is no module named pyperclip

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\Scripts\pw.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sys, pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

this is my batch file:

```
@C:\Python36-32\python.exe C:\Python36-32\Scripts\pw.py %*
@pause
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x

Answer (score 0):

You may have to download the module from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip
i am not sure why it isn't finding the module via the python terminal but this might help.

Comment: I can't seem to do anything with that file on windows. When I use 7zip to extract it, it makes a folder with another tar file in it and trying to extract that does nothing