# Unable to install packages PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, package, traceback

I am trying to install packages with PyCharm but each time I try to do so it gives me an error:

[image: Picture of the error]

The full command output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 2, in <module>
    import traceback
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'traceback'
```

What would be a way to fix this?

Edit: I am trying to install the "Python packaging tools" which results in that error.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset from the right hand side at the top of the window of the Interpreter and try to install again