# ModuleNotFoundError & ImportError on Module Import Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I've scoured through and found lots of questions with lots of answers but nothing seems to be hitting the mark.

I've set up two files `config.py` and `test.py` under one folder called test.

config includes the code:

```
class Config:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

while test has:

```
try:
    # Trying to find module in the parent package
    from . import config
    print(config.debug)
    del config
except ImportError:
    print('Relative import failed')

try:
    # Trying to find module on sys.path
    import config
    print(config.debug)
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print('Absolute import failed')
```

This has been put together as per the answer supplier on this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x) answer.

Unfortunately I'm getting both errors appearing, when I just try to directly call it `from config import Config` I get ModuleNotFoundError

I'm truly lost on this one and can't figure out where to go from here.

Using Python 3.6, atom.io as my IDE.

Comment: Is your test folder contain an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: no, I was under the belief that python 3.3+ didn't need it anymore?

Comment: If you want to treat your folder as a package its needed. As is mentioned in documentation: The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file .... After that you can simply do `from test import config`. Read more here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Still no luck, I've added in the empty files on the directory level but the same errors are popping up. Does seem to stick at module not found error

Comment: You are still getting the ImportError and ModuleNotFoundError even after adding the __init__.py? Can you update your post to show how you added __init__.py and also the updated import codes?

Comment: **No**, `__init__.py` is **not** needed. That is misinformation. I essentially never create `__init__.py` files unless I need them to actually contain some magic (e.g. `__all__`), and it does not cause problems. The problem here is caused by unrelated typos: trying to access a `debug` attribute that doesn't exist, and trying to treat the class interchangeably with the module that contains it.

Answer (score 3):

```
#test.py

class Test:
    try:
        # Trying to find module in the parent package
        from . import config
        print(config.Config.debug)
        del config
    except ImportError:
        print('Relative import failed')

    try:
        # Trying to find module on sys.path
        import config
        print(config.Config.debug)
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        print('Absolute import failed')


#config.py

class Config:
    debug = True
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

#config.py

In this file, the error was appearing because there was no variable debug = True

```
class Config:
    debug = True
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

#test.py

In this file, the error was appearing because you were executing the print of the import of the file and trying to access the variable in a direct way, that is, you would need 3 steps...
import, class, variable >>> config.Config.debug

```
print(config.Config.debug)
```

I hope it helped you