# Execute a python file from different directory

Tags: python, package, directory-structure

I try to understand how to split up python files belonging to the same project in different directories. If I understood it right I need to use packages as described [here in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

So my structure looks like this:

```
.
├── A
│   ├── fileA.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── B
│   ├── fileB.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

with empty `__init__.py` files and

```
$ cat A/fileA.py 
def funA():
    print("hello from A")

$ cat B/fileB.py 
from A.fileA import funA

if __name__ == "__main__":
    funA()
```

Now I expect that when I execute `B/fileB.py` I get `"Hello from A"`, but instead I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'A'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x similar to your problem ?

Comment: @madjaoue thank you, but the question you linked refers to two files in the same directory

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the same as: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

> TL;DR: you can't do relative imports from the file you execute since
>   **main** module is not a part of a package.

**As main:**

```
python B/fileB.py
```

*Output:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p2/m2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from p1.m1 import funA
ImportError: No module named p1.m1
```

**As a module (not main):**

```
python -m B.fileB
```

*Output:*

```
hello from A
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I exactly understand what you mean with *main* module. But when I run python with the `-m` parameter I get this error:
`/usr/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'B/fileB.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B/fileB')`

Comment: My bad, it's a typo. You can run it as `python -m B.fileB`.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Only if you have the time, could you add some details about how (and why) this works? Or just some links to a helpful documentation? I didn't read much about this when I was looking through the official documentation.

Comment: ok sorry, I didn't notice you have already added another link. Thank you!

Comment: I just edited my post to a very detailed explanation.  Hope it's clearer ;)

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to add module `A` into the path of fileB.py by adding

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'absolute/path/to/A/')
```

to the top of fileB.py.

Comment: Then I would have to add this line to every file that references to code in other directories? Is this the standard way in python?

Comment: But yes, your approach works :) But doesn't seem like a good solution for bigger projects

Comment: In bigger projects, you would have both `A` and `B` being submodules of some module `module`, and then change the import statement to `from module.A.fileA import funA`. Then you only need to add `module` into the path of any script you want to run (so only in `fileB.py`, in your example). You do not need to add it in any other files, as long as you don't execute them as the `__main__` script.