# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkSimpleDialog' - Python Shell

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this code which I got [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mV5vZa9lkzc):

```
from tkinter import *

import tkSimpleDialog

import tkMessageBox

 root = Tk()
 w = Label(root, text= "My Program")
 w.pack()

 tkMessageBox.showinfo("Welcome", "Add welcome message here")
```

but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp1nh.png)
 error occured:

I already look here [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x), but I can't understand the answers. I'm still new about these stuff.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using python 3, you will need to import it as `tkinter.simpledialog`. Likewise, MessageBox has been changed to `tkinter.messagebox`.