# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxx.conf'; 'xxx' is not a package

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.7

I have the following project structure:

```
xxx
├── xxx
|   ├── settings
|   └── tests
|   └── __init__.py
|   └── conf.py
|   └── xxx.py
|   └── utils.py
```

Those are the imports that I have in each file.

xxx.py

```
from xxx import utils, conf
from xxx.conf import BASE_DIR
```

conf.py

```
import os
import yaml
```

utils.py

```
import os
import shutil
from typing import List, Optional, Tuple, Dict, Union
import requests
```

When I run my app with

```
python3 xxx.py
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' from 'xxx' (/Users/yyyyy/workscpace/xxx/xxx/xxx.py)
```

When I run my test suite with pytest, I don't get any errors.

I have tried to change the import to (because those files are modules in my package):

```
import utils
import conf
```

In this case, I can run my app with no errors but I get the following error when trying to run pytest

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's in `__init__.py`?

Comment: Nothing, it's empty

Comment: Unless you have a very, very, very good reason to name a sub package like the parent package: just don't. It safes *a lot* of headache.

Comment: The top 'xxx' folder is the project root and not a package.

Answer (score 1):

Is your package's name `xxx.py`?

If those two have the same name, Python will import the `xxx.py` not the package `xxx` because Python looks for packages in `sys.path` sequentially, and the first entry is usually the current directory (of the project).

Otherwise, if you only have python xxx.py, sys.path will have current path in xxx package, but if you use pytest import xxx, the current not in xxx package, python will not find package or .py in xxx package and can't find utils.py and conf.py
in this case you can try to write `from . import *` in _ *init* _.py or in xxx.py write `from . import utils, conf`

Comment: Hi @jbwabg, could you please clarify your answer? I think you made a good point here, only it's a bit unclear...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very similar to [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x)

When you run `python3 xxx.py`, it becomes the main module, so it's looking for something like `xxx/xxx/xxx/utils.py`.
When you run `pytest`, it is aware of the `xxx` package, and therefore picks up the `utils` and `conf` as you expect.

If you use absolute imports, the tests fail because python is now looking for `utils` on `sys.path`. But `python3 xxx.py` works because the local folder is added to your `sys.path`.

A clean solution would be to create a `main.py` one level up from `utils.py` and `conf.py` and import your code from there, like:

```
# main.py
from xxx import utils, conf

def main():
    # do stuff here

if __name__ == __main__:
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I run my app with
>
> ```
> python3 xxx.py
> ```

This means that your current working directory is *inside* the `xxx` package. There is no `xxx.conf` to discover, because the top level seen to python is at `conf`, `utils` etc.

Run your app from the parent folder using the `-m` switch:

```
python3 -m xxx.xxx
```

---

Note that it is a good idea to avoid naming sub packages like the main package. This avoids confusion, *especially* when you or someone else has to maintain your package in the future.

Comment: I can run my app with `python -m xxx.xxx`, why is that? In "main package" are you referring to the top 'xxx' folder? this one is only the project (and repository) root, it's not a package.