# Python: why do I get an error when I call osgeo on mac?

Tags: python, gdal

I try to import `ogr` from `osgeo`

```
from osgeo import ogr
```

but I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'
```

Before I installed `GDAL`, if I do:

```
pip3 install gdal
Requirement already satisfied: gdal in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.4.1)

which pip
/anaconda3/bin/pip

which python
/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Comment: Show us how you're running the code.  (i.e. are you typing `python myprogram.py` at a command line, are you using a GUI, etc.)

Comment: @JohnGordon I am using `anaconda` and now I get a different error I typed above

Comment: This might help you. [github issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/gdal-feedstock/issues/111)

Comment: Is `pip3` the correct way to install anaconda packages?

Comment: Do `which pip` and `which python` give you executables in the same location?

Comment: @eduffy did. If I try to install `gdal` via `pip install gdal` I get an error

Comment: There appears to be a [complete gdal installer](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks/) available for macOS, have you tried that?

Comment: @Asmus I am trying but after different trials I have multiple version on my mac of `gdal`

Comment: which version of gdal do you have installed? I'd try to get it down to just one version

Answer (score 0):

It will likely do with relative and absolute imports, provided you installed the package correctly. Either doing a simple module name alteration or changing where/how you import should fix this. A detailed explanation is in the top 2 answers to the question linked below.

[Relative imports - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/relative-imports-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x)

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing is mainly because you are installing the packages with pip3 and it is stored to the site-packages in the native python3.

You are running the code with the python which came with anaconda. The simplest way to solve this is to install gdal with conda.

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```