# ModuleNotFoundError after installing tableauserverclient

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am writing my first python script to establish a connection with tableau.

Getting the below error:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tableauserverclient'
```

I have installed tableauserverclient using the command:

```
pip install tableauserverclient
```

`Pip version: 19.3.1`

`tableauserverclient version: 0.9`

Comment: Have you make sure to install the package on the correct environment? What version of python are you using? What version of anaconda or virtualenv?

Comment: i am using Python38-32. Also i can see the tableauserverclient inside Python38-32\Lib\site-packages folder.

Comment: Going off of @jalazbe , if you have both python 2.x and python 3.x installed, try again with `pip3 install tableauserverclient`.

Comment: Try using the command `pip -V`to tell us what version of pip you are using and `pip list`(to see if the package is installed)

Comment: my pip version is 19.3.1 and tableauserverclient is shown in the list with version 0.9

Comment: Just to make sure. if you do: `pip install tableauserverclient`then execute `python`and then `import tableauserverclient`you get the error you mention on the question? Are you using Anaconda Navigator ?

Comment: I am using pycharm. Had to configure tableauserverclient in the settings. It worked. Thank You guys. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried relative vs abosulte imports?
See this post for more information, there are a lot of fixes for your problem. [relative Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/relative-imports-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x)
And please give an example code from you code that creates that error