# Python 3: Problem with nested relative imports (direct and indirect execution of code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, execution, relative-import

I´ve the following project structure:

```
|- main.py
|- lib/
   |- foo.py
   |- bar.py
```

Example code main.py

```
from lib.foo import foo
from lib.bar import bar

def main():
    bar()
    foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example code lib/bar.py

```
def bar():
    # do something
```

Example code lib/foo.py

```
from .bar import bar

def foo():
    bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

**Now the problem:** If I execute the main.py everything is working fine. If I execute foo.py I get the following python error:

*ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package*

I found a similar problem on this Thread and this comment fixed my problem so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45556023/4428711

Solution **so far** for foo.py:

```
try:
    from bar import bar
except ImportError:
    from .bar import bar

def foo():
    bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

**Now my question:** Is there a better solution for nested relative imports than this regarding direct and indirect executions?

Comment: This difference in behavior is because the package `__main__` is special: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/1032785

Comment: Yes, this was one of my first search results. BrenBarn explained it pretty amazing. I understand why this error appears and how to avoid it by running it with the -m tag as a module and not as a script. But how could I handle it for automate testing? This is my major problem.

Answer (score 0):

create file `__init__.py` 
in lib directory

```
from .foo import *
from .bar import *
```

Example code main.py

```
import lib

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lib.foo()
```

Example code lib/foo.py

```
import lib

def foo():
    lib.bar()

foo()
```