# ImportError and ModuleNotFoundError: how to get a script running from the command line?

Tags: python, path, python-import, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I have a project with the following structure:

```
HorticulturalSalesPrediction/
    Docker
    HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API/
        optimization/
            __init__.py
            optuna_optim.py
        preprocess/
            __init__.py
            base_dataset.py
        utils/
            __init__.py
            FeatureAdder.py
            helper_functions.py
    __init__.py
    optim_pipeline.py
    run.py
```

In the script `run.py` I import stuff like this:

```
import optim_pipeline
from utils import helper_functions
```

And in the script `optim_pipeline.py` I import stuff like this:

```
from utils import helper_functions
from preprocess import base_dataset
from optimization import optuna_optim
```

I developed this framework with the IDE PyCharm and when I run it with the 'Run'-Button, the framework works fine. But when I want to run it over a terminal with `python3 run.py` or `python3 -m run.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    import optim_pipeline
  File "/home/josef/Schreibtisch/HorticulturalSalesPrediction/HorticulturalSalesPrediction/HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API/optim_pipeline.py", line 4, in <module>
    from preprocess import base_dataset
  File "/home/josef/Schreibtisch/HorticulturalSalesPrediction/HorticulturalSalesPrediction/HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API/preprocess/base_dataset.py", line 8, in <module>
    from HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API.utils import FeatureAdder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API'
```

I know that there are already tons of questions and solutions to this whole python import topic ([Relative imports - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43728431/14553595), [Call a function from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file/20309470#20309470), [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912), ...), but none of these worked for me.

When I print `sys.path` I among others receive `'/home/josef/Schreibtisch/HorticulturalSalesPrediction/HorticulturalSalesPrediction/HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API'`, so all this stuff should be available at the syspath.

I also tried to do relative and absolute imports. But with these attempts I reveice `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` or `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` errors (e.g. when I try `from . import optim_pipeline`).

Comment: did you try to launch script.py as `python -m script` statement? What are you typing in the shell?

Comment: Yes, I also tried `python3 -m run.py`, but got the same error ModuleNotFoundError like running `python3 run.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my mistake.
The solution is to run `python3 -m HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API.run` in the HorticulturalSalesPrediction folder.
Then it works like expected.
I just then had to adjust some imports:

```
from HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API.utils import helper_functions
from . import optim_pipeline
```

and

```
from HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API.utils import helper_functions
from HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API.preprocess import base_dataset
from HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API.optimization import optuna_optim
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the modules and updating python.

Update **HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API**

Comment: `HorticulturalSalesPrediction_API` is a folder or module, respectively, I created by myself, so it's not an external package, that I installed and imported.

Comment: try reinstalling it or remaking it