# Import models across directories

Tags: python

```
Backend
├── Flaskr
│   └── __init__.py
└── models.py
```

I want to import `model.py` into `__init__.py`

I tried `from models import setup_db, Book`
I tried `from backend.models import setup_db, Book`

I end up up getting one of these two errors:

> `from models import setup_db, Book`
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

or

> `from backend.models import setup_db, Book`
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'

Comment: Your package is named `Backend`, not `backend`; case matters. Rename the folder from `Backend` to `backend` and try again. And are you sure the folder `Backend` is contained in is in `sys.path`?

Comment: This post has the same issue of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/relative-imports-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C95.2403). Is there something else on yout case that the other hasn't?

Answer (score -1):

Here is something to try, not sure how it will work

First import sys in **init**.py

```
import sys
```

Second, add the path / directory of models.py

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/the/folder/path/name-package/')
```

Then, make another file called **init**.py, leave it blank. Leave it in the same directory as models.py. This is so python knows it is a package.

Lastly, import models.py from the backend folder

```
from backend import models
```

I am not sure if this will work but it may be worth a try if other peoples suggestions don't work very well.

Thanks for your time.

Edit:
You may also be able to use this instead of using the exact path.

```
sys.path.insert("../")
```

this in theory will select the path of the backend by going back a directory.