# Helper functions in another file, ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a simple Python project using scrapy. My file structure looks like this:

```
top_level_folder
|-scraper
|--spiders
|---help_functions.py
|---<some more files>
|--items.py
|--pipelines.py
|--settings.py
|--<some more files>
```

help_functions.py has a couple functions defined, like `add_to_items_buffer`.

In pipelines.py, I'm attempting to do...

```
from help_functions import add_to_items_buffer

...

class BlahPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
       ...
       add_to_items_buffer(item)
       ...
```

When I try to run this, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'help_functions'`. Doing `from spiders.help_functions import add_to_items_buffer` throws a similar error.

What's going on here? I imagine I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about how Python imports work.

Comment: [__init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43859946/19276472) explained it for me! It's a matter of relative vs absolute imports depending on where the file you're calling lives.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `add_to_items_buffer` function in the `top_level_folder/scraper/spiders/help_functions.py` file and the `pipelines.py` at `top_level_folder/scraper/pipelines.py`, you need to import it like so:

```py
from spiders.help_functions import add_to_items_buffer
```

Comment: This is not quite it. As I mention in the question, doing `from spiders.help_functions ...` throws a similar error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spiders'"

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your `help_functions.py` file is located in *scraper/spiders*.

The error you have is because you are directly calling *`help_functions`* which is not located at the same directory level as *`pipelines.py`*.

Solution example

```py
# old
from help_functions import add_to_items_buffer

# new
from spiders.help_functions import add_to_items_buffer
```

Whenever you import a file, you must refer to its path

Comment: This is not quite it. As I mention in the question, doing `from spiders.help_functions ...` throws a similar error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spiders'"