# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x' when trying to run my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, runtime-error, python-import

Really at my wits end, tried multiple solutions including using a `setup.py` file, changing relative imports to absolute imports and vice-versa, package restructuring, ensuring each package as an __init__.py file and more. Any help would be appreciated. I have simplified my project below.

My project structure is as follows:

```
myProject
   |
   |__ src
        |
        |__ foo
        |     - __init__.py
        |    |
        |    |__ bar
        |          - __init__.py
        |         |
        |         |__ baz
        |              - __init__.py
        |              - baz_functions.py
        |              - baz_watch.py
        |
        | - __init__.py
        | - project_code.py
        | - main.py
```

As for the files:

`main.py`

```
import project_code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    project_code.run()
```

`project_code.py`

```
import foo.bar.baz.baz_functions

def run():
    print('Hello World!')
```

`baz_watch.py`

```
from baz_functions import function_1, function_2

print('Watching...')
```

`baz_functions.py`

```
def function_1():
   print('I am function 1')

def function_2():
   print('I am function 2')
```

Naturally, without the: `import foo.bar.baz.baz_functions` in `project_code.py`, the code runs just fine.

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\myProject\src\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import project_code
  File "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\myProject\src\project_code.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo.bar.baz.baz_functions
  File "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\myProject\src\foo\bar\baz\baz_watch.py", line 1, in <module>
    from baz_functions import function_1, function_2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'baz_functions'
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/relative-imports-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`baz_functions` is not a top-level module; it lives in the package `foo.bar.baz` and, using an *absolute* import, has to be imported as such.

A *relative* import can use `.` to refer to a module in the same package as the importing module:

```
from .baz_functions import function1, function2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Infuriating that the answer was so simple.

Answer (score 1):

In your `baz_watch.py` file, you have to import `baz_functions` using relative import (adding `.` before module name). By doing this, you are telling python to look for the module in the same directory as your `baz_watch.py` file. Otherwise it may look for the package in your python path and throw error. Here is the modified code.

```
from .baz_functions import function_1, function_2

print('Watching...')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Infuriating that the answer was so simple.